# How to rewrite token with text in tree grammar?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr3

This is my tree grammar:

```
grammar t;
options{
  output = AST;
}
type
  :
  'NVARCHAR' -> "VARCHAR"
  ;
```

ANTLR3 3.1.3 says:

```
syntax error: antlr: t.g:12:5: unexpected token: 'NVARCHAR'
```

What's wrong here? I took it from [this article](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/~admin/2008/04/11/Rewrite+rules).

ps. I'm using this grammar later in order to get AST out of it. Once the AST is retrieved I'm walking through it and add every token's text to some string buffer. The idea of the rewriting above is to replace certain tokens. I'm doing language-to-language mapping (SQL to SQL dialect, to be more specific).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note the first sentence Terence starts with: *"just had some cool ideas about a semantic rule specification language..."*. That's what the first example is: an idea. It's not valid syntax.

There are (at least) two options for you:

---

### 1. rewrite the text in the token immediately

```
grammar T;

options{
  output=AST;
}

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("NVARCHAR"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.type();
  }
}

type
  :  NVARCHAR {System.out.println("token=" + $NVARCHAR.text);}
  ;

NVARCHAR
  :  'NVARCHAR' {setText("VARCHAR");}
  ;
```

But this only adjusts the `text`, not the `type` of the token, which remains a `NVARCHAR` type.

---

### 2. use an imaginary token:

```
grammar T;

options{
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  VARCHAR='VARCHAR';
}

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("NVARCHAR"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.type();
  }
}

type
  :  NVARCHAR -> VARCHAR
  ;

NVARCHAR
  :  'NVARCHAR'
  ;
```

which changes the `text` *and* `type` of the token.

---

As you can see, with both demos, `token=VARCHAR` is being printed to the console:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar TParser 
token=VARCHAR
```

Comment: @Bart I like the first option (with `setText()`), but it doesn't work. ANTLR generates `.java` class which is not compilable: `cannot find symbol method setText(java.lang.String) in TParser`. Any ideas?

Comment: @yegor256, it _does_ work. See the demo I added. My guess is you're trying to call this method inside a parser rule (my suggestion shows this in a lexer rule).

Comment: @Bart I have a tree grammar, as in the question above. Could you please make corrections to my example?

Comment: @yegor256, no, you have posted a combined grammar that outputs an AST. A tree grammar starts with `tree grammar T;` instead of `grammar T;`. Or did you not include your tree grammar? You said you wanted to change the text of the token. The type of the token will just stay `NVARCHAR` (with the text: `"VARCHAR"`). Perhaps it's time to edit your question and add some more information.

Comment: @Bart I added some details to my question, hope that they explain the situation better. You're right, it's a grammar that outputs an AST. I need to get an AST with "already replaced" tokens. Makes sense?

Comment: @yegor256, see my revised answer.

Comment: @Bart, works fine (the fist option you suggested), many thanks for your help! I didn't try the second one, since the first one is more suitable for my case.

Answer (score 1):

in antlr4 replacing text and type can be achieved with the `type` action:

```
OldTokenType: 
    ('Token1' | 'Token2' | 'Token3' ) {setText("New Token");} 
    -> type(NewTokenType);
```